# Javascript Delay/Sleep function

Tags: javascript

I am writing a vanilla javascript function to add a page scrolling animation to my website. The problem is that I want the event listener to pause for the specified millisecond time to give time for the animation to complete since if I scroll normally, the animation will happen multiple times one after the other.

```
/*  Event handler for scroll event  */

// This is a function which allows a time to be passed in miliseconds. This function will then cause a sleep effect for the specified ms time
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// Initial state
var iniState = 0;

// Adding scroll event
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    // Detects new state and compares it with the old one
    if ((document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top > iniState)
        console.log('up');
    else
        console.log('down');
    
    // Saves the new position for iteration.
    iniState = (document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top;

    sleep(2000).then(() => { console.log("test"); });
});
```

I tried the timeout function, but this only delayed the event listener instead of pausing for the period of time. This is a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TViHH.png) to the console in browser if that makes the problem easier to understand.

In summery, I am trying to make a event listener to listen for a scroll event, then wait 2000 milliseconds to wait for the animation to complete. After this the event listener will then start listening again for a scroll event again.

Comment: Where in the code do you run the animation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add the event listener, remove it after it's called, then set a timeout to add it again.

```js
function scrollHandler() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);

    // Detects new state and compares it with the old one
    if ((document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top > iniState)
        console.log('up');
    else
        console.log('down');
    
    // Saves the new position for iteration.
    iniState = (document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top;

    setTimeout(() => window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler), 2000);
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
```

Comment: This fixed my problem. Do you know how I would prevent the default event?

Comment: use `animationend` event instead of setting explicit timeout values.

Comment: @alexkobe what do you mean by default event?

Comment: @AnthumChris no need - also the answer you posted doesn't make sense

Comment: The scroll event. So when the page is scrolled down via a scroll wheel for example. i want to prevent that from happening

Comment: @alexkobe do you only want to prevent vertical scrolling or horizontal as well?

Comment: Both I guess is probably better but I'm only bothered about horizontal scrolling

Comment: @alexkobe where exactly do you run your animation? just store the scroll position at the beginning of your animation and then reset it on each frame

Answer (score 0):

I believe that every time when a browser detects a scroll event, it'll create a new function using your template and put into to a stack.

For example:
scroll detected : 7:41:20s
call stack = [ `function_created_at_7:41:20s`]

The next scroll detected at 7:41:21s :

```
call stack = [ function_created_at_7:41:20s,
function_created_at_7:41:21s

]
```

since the promise and timeout are asynchronous execution, they wait and stay in the call stack.

After 2000s passed,  sleep's callback of `function_created_at_7:41:20s` will be executed

You might have to use global references and some ifs to keep the scroll function into sleep.

Answer (score 0):

```
let is_waiting = false;

document.addEventListener("scroll",(e) => {
    if(!is_waiting) {
        console.log("scrolling...");
        is_waiting = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
            is_waiting = false;
        },2000);
    }        
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let lastScrollStart

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const scrollStart = lastScrollStart = performance.now() // timestamp

  const elAnimated = document.querySelector(...)
  elAnimated.addEventListener('animationend', function onAnimationEnd() {
    elAnimated.removeEventListener('animationend', onAnimationEnd)
    if (scrollStart === lastScrollStart) {
      ...
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: I am quite new to Javascript so could you explain this further for me?